# Customizing scrollbar over QListWidget

Tags: qt

I'd like to implement my own semi-transparent scrollbar, that draws on top of the QListWidget instead of taking up permanent space in its viewport. I do not wish to use QML as my QListWidget and its dynamic content is already fully developed over 6 months now.

How can I achieve that. Stylesheets are useless for that purpose as they will not determine the positioning of the scrollbar. I'd like it to be on top of the QListWidget, not on its side, taking up its space.

I'm talking about something in the neighborhood of this:

[image]

Any hints as to how to do that will be appreciated.

Comment: I think that only way is to create your own QListView-based control and implement custom drawing of scrollbar (now only drawing, but logic too). I'll try to write sample code tomorrow.

Comment: It has to be QListWidget, btw - this is what I'm using as I'm putting live "widgets" into the rows as per my app's requirements. You can't achieve that with QListView's delegation system.

Comment: Delegates are used for drawing content. Scroll is not content. Target is to hide scroll and to implement custom scroll over existing QListWidget.

Comment: Do you have any feedback?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a perfect example of one thing that persistently annoys me about qt - if there is some graphical effect that Qt's designers haven't thought of, creating it on your own is a pain, constant fight against Qt, and usually ends with giving up anyway.

I suspect that you do it with small screens on your mind (cell phones? tablets?), so i guess there is no other way to solve this problem.

What I am trying here is hacky, but otherwise you would probably have to rewrite entire scrollbar yourself just to add those few missing details. My proposition is:

```
#ifndef MYSCROLLBAR_H
#define MYSCROLLBAR_H

#include <QScrollBar>

class MyScrollBar : public QScrollBar
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyScrollBar(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void showEvent ( QShowEvent * event );
signals:

public slots:
   void updateMask();
};

#endif // MYSCROLLBAR_H
```

And in myscrollbar.cpp

```
#include "myscrollbar.h"

#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QRegion>

#include <QStyleOptionSlider>

MyScrollBar::MyScrollBar(QWidget *parent) :
    QScrollBar(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updateMask()));
}

void MyScrollBar::updateMask(){
    QStyleOptionSlider opt;
    initStyleOption(&opt);

    QRegion r(style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ScrollBar, &opt, QStyle::SC_ScrollBarSlider, this));
    r+= style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ScrollBar, &opt, QStyle::SC_ScrollBarAddLine, this);
    r+= style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_ScrollBar, &opt, QStyle::SC_ScrollBarSubLine, this);
    setMask(r);
}

void MyScrollBar::showEvent ( QShowEvent * event ){
    QScrollBar::showEvent(event);
    updateMask();
}
```

Such scroller will be transparent (both visually and event-wise) in any of it's non-vital parts. It still creates some artifacts on widgets laying below it - I guess `setMask()` was never supposed to be used like this. To mitigate it you can connect `valueChanged()` signal to `update()` slot of the viewport of your list widget. This worked nice on my toy-example, but if you embed custom widgets in your list it might become unbearable to cope with. It might also run you into performance problems in case of more complex applications - especially if you write for mobile platforms.

Alternatively you can just "fork" entire QScrollBar class and simply modify it's paintEvent to use less subControls than SC_All - with additional `setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, false);` in constructor it should provide visual transparency. Then you should also forward mouse events (if not hitting anything important) to your viewport of list widget (again, trouble with custom widgets in view).

Now what remains is writing your own layout class (or just manually positioning it) that will put both listview and scrollbar on one another in correct positions - QStackedLayout sounds nice, but it allows only one layer to be visible at any given time - clearly not what we are looking for.

Last step is switching off default scrollbars on view, and connecting signals/slots of the default (invisible) scrollbar to slots/signals of your scrollbar, to achieve effect of actual scrolling.

Shortly this will require a **LOT** of coding to get done. Are you sure that such a simple effect is worth it?

** EDIT: **

I create a layout class for stacking widgets on top of one another - this question gave me motivation to do it finally ;)

```
#ifndef STACKLAYOUT_H
#define STACKLAYOUT_H

#include <QLayout>

class StackLayout : public QLayout
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StackLayout();
    explicit StackLayout(QWidget *parent);
    ~StackLayout();

    void addItem ( QLayoutItem * item );
    int count () const;
    Qt::Orientations expandingDirections () const;
    bool hasHeightForWidth () const;
    int heightForWidth ( int w ) const;
    QLayoutItem * itemAt ( int index ) const;
    bool isEmpty () const;
    QSize maximumSize () const;
    int minimumHeightForWidth ( int w ) const;
    QSize minimumSize () const;
    void setGeometry ( const QRect & r );
    QSize sizeHint () const;
    QLayoutItem * takeAt ( int index );

private:
     QList<QLayoutItem *> itemList;

};

#endif // STACKLAYOUT_H
```

And the stacklayout.cpp file:

```
StackLayout::StackLayout()
    :QLayout()
{}

StackLayout::StackLayout(QWidget *parent) :
    QLayout(parent)
{
}

StackLayout::~StackLayout(){
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        delete item;
    }
}

void StackLayout::addItem ( QLayoutItem * item ){
    itemList.append(item);
}

int StackLayout::count () const{
    return itemList.count();
}

Qt::Orientations StackLayout::expandingDirections () const{
    Qt::Orientations result = 0;
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        result = result | item->expandingDirections();
    }
    return result;
}

bool StackLayout::hasHeightForWidth () const{
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        if (item->hasHeightForWidth())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int StackLayout::heightForWidth ( int w ) const{
    int result = 0;
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        if (item->hasHeightForWidth())
            result = qMax(result, item->heightForWidth(w));
    }
    return result;
}

QLayoutItem * StackLayout::itemAt ( int index ) const{
    if (index<itemList.count())
        return itemList[index];
    return 0;
}

bool StackLayout::isEmpty () const{
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        if (!item->isEmpty())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

QSize StackLayout::maximumSize () const{
    QSize result=QLayout::maximumSize();
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        result = result.boundedTo(item->maximumSize());
    }
    return result;
}

int StackLayout::minimumHeightForWidth ( int w ) const{
    int result = 0;
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        if (item->hasHeightForWidth())
            result = qMax(result, item->minimumHeightForWidth(w));
    }
    return result;
}

QSize StackLayout::minimumSize () const{
    QSize result=QLayout::minimumSize();
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        result = result.expandedTo(item->minimumSize());
    }
    return result;
}

void StackLayout::setGeometry ( const QRect & r ){
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        item->setGeometry(r);
    }
}

QSize StackLayout::sizeHint () const{
    QSize result=QSize(0,0);
    QLayoutItem *item;
    foreach (item, itemList){
        result = result.expandedTo(item->sizeHint());
    }
    return result;
}

QLayoutItem * StackLayout::takeAt ( int index ){
    if (index < itemList.count())
        return itemList.takeAt(index);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming you already have some nice transparent scrollbar, to insert it you would do:

```
QWidget* w = new QWidget();

StackLayout* sl = new StackLayout(w);
QListView* lv = new QListView(w);
sl->addWidget(lv);
QHBoxLayout* hbl = new QHBoxLayout();
sl->addItem(hbl);

TransparentScrollBar* tsc = new TransparentScrollBar(w);

hbl->addWidget(tsc,0);
hbl->insertStretch(0,1);
```

Comment: BTW If you decide to code it anyway I can offer some more code/help.

Comment: Forgive me, but that file is TransparentScrollBar class? 
I suppose it is a simple widget.

Comment: By Transparent scrollbar I meant something like in Dmitry Sazonov's answer.

Comment: Since Qt 4.4, QStackedLayout has `StackingMode::StackAll` to show all the widgets at the same time https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html#StackingMode-enum . This custom layout should not be needed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Here is sample code for your questoin.

Not done:
Mouse dragging of scroller

Done:
Support of any mouse hover/leave events
Support of scrolling
Scroll bar is transparent for mouse events

It is good start point for any customization depending on you task. Usage:

```
GUI::MegaScrollBar *bar = new GUI::MegaScrollBar( ui->listWidget );
bar->resize( 40, 30 ); // First arg - width of scroller
```

MegaScrollBar.h

```
#ifndef MEGASCROLLBAR_H
#define MEGASCROLLBAR_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPointer>


class QAbstractItemView;
class QResizeEvent;

namespace GUI
{

    class MegaScrollBar
        : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MegaScrollBar( QAbstractItemView *parentView );
        ~MegaScrollBar();

    private slots:
        void updatePos();

    private:
        bool eventFilter( QObject *obj, QEvent *event );
        void onResize( QResizeEvent *e );
        void paintEvent( QPaintEvent * event );
        void resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * event );

        QPointer< QAbstractItemView > m_view;
        QPointer< QWidget > m_scrollBtn;
    };

}


#endif // MEGASCROLLBAR_H
```

MegaScrollBar.cpp

```
#include "MegaScrollBar.h"

#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>

#include "ScrollButton.h"


namespace GUI
{

    MegaScrollBar::MegaScrollBar( QAbstractItemView *parentView )
        : QWidget( parentView, Qt::FramelessWindowHint )
        , m_view( parentView )
    {
        Q_ASSERT( parentView );

        setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground );
        setAttribute( Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents );

        m_scrollBtn = new ScrollButton( parentView );
        m_scrollBtn->setFixedSize( 20, 40 );

        m_view->installEventFilter( this );

        QScrollBar *sb = m_view->verticalScrollBar();
        connect( sb, SIGNAL( valueChanged( int ) ), this, SLOT( updatePos() ) );
    }

    MegaScrollBar::~MegaScrollBar()
    {
        removeEventFilter( m_view );
    }

    bool MegaScrollBar::eventFilter( QObject *obj, QEvent *event )
    {
        switch ( event->type() )
        {
        case QEvent::Enter:
            m_scrollBtn->show();
            break;

        case QEvent::Leave:
            m_scrollBtn->hide();
            break;

        case QEvent::Resize:
            onResize( static_cast< QResizeEvent * >( event ) );
            break;
        }

        return QWidget::eventFilter( obj, event );
    }

    void MegaScrollBar::onResize( QResizeEvent *e )
    {
        const int x = e->size().width() - width();
        const int y = 0;
        const int w = width();
        const int h = e->size().height();

        move( x, y );
        resize( w, h );

        updatePos();
    }

    void MegaScrollBar::updatePos()
    {
        QScrollBar *sb = m_view->verticalScrollBar();
        const int min = sb->minimum();
        const int val = sb->value();
        const int max = sb->maximum();
        const int x = pos().x() + ( width() - m_scrollBtn->width() ) / 2;

        if ( max == 0 )
        {
            m_scrollBtn->move( x, pos().y() );
            return ;
        }

        const int maxY = height() - m_scrollBtn->height();
        const int y = ( maxY * val ) / max;

        m_scrollBtn->move( x, y );
    }

    void MegaScrollBar::paintEvent( QPaintEvent * event )
    {
        Q_UNUSED( event );
        QPainter p( this );
        QRect rc( 0, 0, rect().width() - 1, rect().height() - 1 );

        // Draw any scroll background
        p.fillRect( rc, QColor( 255, 255, 200, 100 ) );
    }

    void MegaScrollBar::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * event )
    {
        Q_UNUSED( event );
        updatePos();
    }

}
```

Preview:

[image: Sample]

It is possible to set up any widget for scroll button: Here is custom one:
ScrollButton.h

```
#ifndef SCROLLBUTTON_H
#define SCROLLBUTTON_H

#include <QWidget>


namespace GUI
{

    class ScrollButton
        : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        ScrollButton( QWidget *parent );
        ~ScrollButton();

    private:
        void paintEvent( QPaintEvent * event );
    };

}


#endif // SCROLLBUTTON_H
```

ScrollButton.cpp

```
#include "ScrollButton.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QGraphicsOpacityEffect>
#include <QColor>


namespace GUI
{

    ScrollButton::ScrollButton( QWidget *parent )
        : QWidget( parent )
    {
        QGraphicsOpacityEffect *op = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect( this );
        op->setOpacity( 0.5 );
        setGraphicsEffect( op );
    }

    ScrollButton::~ScrollButton()
    {
    }

    void ScrollButton::paintEvent( QPaintEvent * event )
    {
        Q_UNUSED( event );

        // Draw any scroll button
        QPainter p( this );
        QRect rc( 5, 5, rect().width() - 6, rect().height() - 6 );

        p.fillRect( rc, QColor( 0, 0, 0, 255 ) );
    }

}
```

Please comment, if you can't handle mouse interaction.

Comment: Will `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents` not disable all mouse funcionality on such scrollbar? The only way I see to get it working would be to filter mouse events (or intercept some other way i.e. by subclassing tree widget perhaps) from viewport and feed it your scrollbar widget. This will become increasingly difficult if you have custom widgets in your view. Applying a mask as I proposed might be an option.

Comment: Or do you mean your scrollbar is meant just for information, and not for active scrolling your widget using it?

Comment: For interaction you may set any widget in MegaScrollBar::MegaScrollBar(). Also should be implemented redirecting of mouse events from m_scrollBtn widget.

Comment: Btw, there are a lot of possibilities for implementing such functionality (With transculent widget or not). Main idea is to add custom widget inside QListWidget and to track some events (mouse + scroll).